# Select a window from window list in Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I would like to select a window title from the list of window titles returned by robot framework. Including below line in .robot file gives me a list of open windows.

```
${titles} =    Get Window Titles
```

I have a scenario where `titles` returns same window titles (there are two web pages with the same title) and I want to select the second one.

```
titles = ['Google', 'Google']
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: why don't you select windows using window handles?

Comment: @GaurangShah Could you suggest a way to get window handles?

Comment: `List Windows`
http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#List%20Windows